# Addition commutativity in series

Tags: calculus

Given a series
$$1-\dfrac{1}{2}+\dfrac{1}{3}-\dfrac{1}{4}+\dfrac{1}{5}-\dfrac{1}{6}+ \ldots=\ln 2$$

Can I rearrange the order and still get the sum is 1? Why or why not?

I think the answer is no, because the addition is commutative in the set of rational, so no matter how I rearrange the order of the series, I still got the same result. Am I correct?

Comment: $1-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}...= \ln 2$

Comment: Check [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_convergence) and the [Riemann series theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_series_theorem#Statement_of_the_theorem).

Comment: Take a look at [Riemann Series Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_series_theorem).

Comment: is there another way to answer this problem, because Reimamn series theorem is on section 7.5, and I haven't learnt section 7.1 yet.

Comment: This page might be helpful https://archive.org/stream/coursepuremath00hardrich#page/n456/mode/1up especially if you mix these ideas with something like the mean value theorem I think you can convince yourself rearrangement should work in this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rearrange the order of series and get the sum 1. It seems that there's no better way to explain this except Riemann Series Theorem.

In general, we can't except the same sum when the order of series is rearranged before the absolute convergence of this series is showed.

$\sum_{i=1}^\infty \dfrac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}$ is an example since $\sum_{i=1}^\infty \dfrac{1}{n}$ doesn't convergent.